# subprocess ends when exiting the script in python

Tags: python

I have a created a script that checks if some other script is running.
If the script has stuck for some case i want to restart the script.

Here is my code

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import call 
import datetime
import time
from time import ctime

statinfo = os.stat('nemo_logs/nemo_log_file_' + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '.txt')
for i in range(1):
    first_size = statinfo.st_size
    time.sleep(10)
    if statinfo.st_size > first_size:
        print("SCRIPT IS RUNNING")
    else:
        print("SCRIPT IS NOT RUNNING. TRYING TO KILL THE SCRIPT...")
        os.system("pkill -9 -f selenium_nemo.py")
        print("SCRIPT KILLED. TRYING TO RESTART THE SCRIPT...")
        subprocess.call("python /root/btree/selenium_nemo.py", shell=True)
        print("SCRIPT STARTED")
```

When i call the `subprocess.call` the script strarts but its executing inside the 'ckeck' script. If i stop executing the check-script the subprocess ends. The check script is on crontab and i want after starting the script that has stuck to exit the check script.
How i can achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure if it's your main problem, but the value stored in `statinfo` is a tuple that won't magically update. After waiting 10 seconds, you have to call `os.stat()` again.

Comment: Hi @lenz , the statinfo is working fine. I can get the first size of the text and later recheck it. This script is still on developing. I'am going to make some changes later to the script but this is my main problem for now

Comment: I'm just saying your `if` condition is never going to be true, because `statinfo.st_size` won't change even if the file's size changes. You could just as well write `if False:`

Comment: you are right. The above script will never get to the else condition. On my tests i'am forcing the script to get to the else condition. Thanks for you Suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `python /root/btree/selenium_nemo.py` directly, you could call `nohup python /root/btree/selenium_nemo.py &`. This will separate your new process from the calling process, so it will survive the stopping of your python script.

Comment: Hi Christian, i'am getting this. SCRIPT KILLED. TRYING TO RESTART THE SCRIPT...
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out' . The script starts succesfully but when i terminame the cron-script the other script stops from working

Comment: Did you check if the script gets restarted successfully? Is it running before you terminate the cron-script?

Comment: Yes the script starts succesfully. 1396  1.6  0.2  80048 24220 pts/1    S+   12:15   0:00 python /root/btree/selenium_nemo.py . But after termination of the check script the selenium_nemo.py stops

Comment: you should add & at the end of command line. That is, 

    nohup python /root/btree/selenium_nemo.py &

Comment: @Hooting, thanks, forgot that. Added it to my answer.